# Solve equation with variables inside and outside cos

Tags: problem-solving

I have an issue with following problem:

A line needs to be intersected with a cosinus function.

My line would be

$\displaystyle l_1 = \binom{x_1}{y_1} + s\binom{u_1}{v_1}$

My function for a curved line in 2D is

$\displaystyle g: y_2 = d + a + a * (-cos(f * x_2))$

I need the first intersection (the smallest s > 0). How do I do that? I stand at

$s * v_1 + a * cos(f * (x_1 + s * u_1)) = y_1 - a - d$

and have no idea how to solve for s from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is of the form
$s+A\cos(b+c\ s) = d$.
Generally, you can't give an expression
for the solution - it can only be done numerically.

By a linear transformation,
this can be written as
$p x+q\cos(x) = r$.
When mathematicians
noticed that 
they often needed to solve
$x e^x = y$
for $x$,
they invented a function
(the Lambert W function)
that solved it.
Similarly,
you could create a function
(the Roth C function)
that solves
$\cos(x)/x = y$ for $x$
and give the solution to your equation
in terms of $C$.

Until such a function exists,
you will have to be content
with solving the equation numerically.

Comment: Er, okay, I will refrain from trying to invent something, and instead do it numerically :)